# Longest Chain vs Heaviest Chain

Tags: blockchain, mining, blockchain-fork, reward

I was reading the book "Mastering Blockchain" and came across the concept of the Heaviest chain vs Longest chain under Ethereum Section.

This is the figure that I am unable to understand.

[image]

My question is What exactly is the difference between the longest chain rule and the heaviest chain rule?
Is there a possibility of chain being rejected despite being long but not the heaviest? How and Why?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is What exactly is the difference between the longest chain rule and the heaviest chain rule?

The heaviest chain counts [uncle (ommer) blocks](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/u/uncle-block-cryptocurrency.asp). As far as I know, the uncle block concept was introduced with Ethereum and does not exist on older blockchains like Bitcoin.

Comment: Okay so as far as i know there are multiple uncle blocks attached to the main chain right? How exactly we are going to label a certain uncle's chain as the heaviest chain?